# MongoDB Java retrieval becomes very slow

Tags: java, mongodb

I am running a Java problem as below:

```
MongoDBManager db = new MongoDBManager(dbName, "FreqUserLog");
List<Object> distinctUIDs = db.getDistinct("uid");

int userNum = 0;
LinkedList<DBObject> samples = new LinkedList<DBObject>();
for( Object uid_obj : distinctUIDs ) {
    System.out.format( "user %d%n", ++userNum );

    BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject();
    filter.put( "uid", String.valueOf(uid_obj) );
    DBCursor cursor = db.findAll(filter);

    /////////////////////////////////////// 
    while( cursor.hasNext() ) {
        DBObject userlog = cursor.next();

        // do nothing temporarily   
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////
}
```

BACKGROUND: The program first gets distinct user IDs and then retrieves all logs of each user. In the MongoDB, there are 47,000 users. I set the VM variable to "-Xms20480m".

PROBLEM: The program runs very fast initially (5s for 1000 users). but after processing 1000 users, it becomes slow (1s for 5 users). Sometimes that number is 1300 or 1900. It seems that it will take one day to process all user logs. I also used Python+PyMongo to write a same program. I met the same problem.

I also tried to comment the block between "/////////////////". The program finished very fast. The count of log in each cursor is about 200. I do not know what the problem is.

EDIT:
I have indexes for "uid" and "url".
The log structure is like:

```
{"_id": *****
 "url": *****
 "Geo": *****
 "Log count": 3
 "Log0":{
          "event":*****
          "eventcode":*****
          "time": *****
          "ip": *****
          }
  "Log1":{
          "event":*****
          "eventcode":*****
          "time": *****
          "ip": *****
          }
   "Log3":{
          "event":*****
          "eventcode":*****
          "time": *****
          "ip": *****
          }
 }
```

Comment: what's the collection structure in your database, do you have all logs of a user in an embedded array? and do you have any index?

Comment: Is it possible, that some of the documents are very large?

Comment: Have you run mongostat while running your code? What's the output? Can you edit the question to include some of the output? Have you run an explain on the query? Can you edit the question to include output from explain?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're doing a new query for each distinct `uid` and not using a $in?  You're likely doing thousands of queries to get all your data back out.